# How to select next <div> without id or class from <img> nested in another <div>

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Here's our html:

```
<div>
    <div>
        ...SOME CONTENT...
        <div><img class="open-inhalt"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        ...SOME MORE CONTENT...
    </div>
<div>
```

And here our jQuery:

```
$('.open-inhalt')
    .click(function(){
    $('SOME MORE CONTENT DIV').animate({'height': 0}, 500);
    })
```

How do we select the div containing '...some more content...' without having to assign it an id or class? The HTML is a common pattern repeated throughout the web page, but always with different ids.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: If it’s with different `ids` why not use them as the selector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the html structure in each case is the same (as you stated above) then you could do the following:

```
$('.open-inhalt').on('click', function() {
   var somemorediv = $(this).parent().parent().next();
   somemorediv.animate({'height': 0}, 500);
});
```

Also I would recommend having the hidden content set to display:none and then reveal with `somemorediv.slideDown(500)` where `500` is the length of time to slide in milliseconds. To hide the content you can then use `.slideUp(500)`.

Comment: Thanks for the slideDown, slideUp recommendation. Don't have to capture dynamic heights anymore and runs nicer and smoother!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this would be done in jQuery, but with native JS, you just use the nextSibling method. So you'd get the parent, get the nextSibling, and then get the child (If necessary)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nextSibling?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FNode.nextSibling

I'm sure you can easily find the jQuery syntax to accomplish the same thing with a quick Google search.

EDIT:
Looks like it's pretty easy with jQuery, and you can ever specify that you want the next DIV. http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Node.parentNode` or `Node.parentElement` for getting parent node/element. For getting element after some node you can use `Node.nextSibling`.

[`Node.nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nextSibling)

[`Node.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.parentNode)

[`Node.parentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.parentElement)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
var nextDiv = $(this).parents('body > div > div').next();
```

or

```
var nextDiv = $(this).parent().parent().next();
```

where `this` is your `<img>` element.

Eventually you can use something more specific than `body`, if the shown structure has some specific container.

Answer (score 0):

First, a note: it's generally inadvisable to navigate the DOM tree using relative accessors because you're making weak assumptions about the structure of the webpage. If someone changes the layout of the HTML structure, or layout isn't consistent throughout, your script will fail. Please use unique `id`s instead to select elements unless absolutely necessary.

You can use jQuery's `.parent([selector])` and `.children([selector])` to navigate the DOM tree fairly easily.

The following code does what you want:

```
$('.open-inhalt').click(function() {
    $(this).parent('div').parent('div').next().animate({'height': 0}, 500);
});
```

Or, to select a specifically indexed node, such as the second `div`:

```
$('.open-inhalt').click(function() {
    $(this).parent('div').parent('div').parent('div')
      .children('div:nth-child(2)').animate({'height': 0}, 500);
});
```

Note: the `'div'` selectors inside each `parent()` method call is optional but provides extra security that you're not accidentally getting lost in the DOM.

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cL66H/2/) for an example.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on using relative accessors. You're right of course but the desire to code less is hard to supress ;)